# Java import using wildcard on left side alternative?

Tags: java

I made a simple plugin for minecraft servers. With version 1.8 they changed there packages.

With version 1.7.x I imported

```
import net.minecraft.util.org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

with the new one I have to import

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

So I tried using a wildcard like so but that doesn't work

```
import *.org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

also importing both is not working

Is there an alternative to support both versions with only 1 exported jar? I hope anyone could give me a hint with cause Google i only found Wildcards for the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that does not work.

The easiest way to make the code work with both versions is to use the `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` prefix and tell users of the old version to include the commons-io.jar file as an additional dependency.